# Auto scroll to header

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I want to scroll effect like these pages

http://www.hugeinc.com/ (After three slide)   -    http://stadiumtechcenter.com/building

For example I have a slider area and when I scroll down it's going to menu. After that standart content block is starting. Now I want to when I scroll up and menu reach the browser top site automaticly jump to page top.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
        divOffset = $('.bottom').offset().top,
        dist = divOffset - scrollTop;

    if (dist > 0) {
        $('html, body').stop().animate({'scrollTop':$('.top').offset().top}, 300);
    }
});
```

Here is the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/zB5bc/

Comment: do you want when clicked on a button goes to top

Comment: No I want to mouse wheel scrolling. Here is the working example http://stadiumtechcenter.com/building when scroll up and page content area reach the top site automatically slide to page top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try something like this:

```
    $(window).on('mousewheel', function(e){
  if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0){

$('html, body').stop().animate({'scrollTop':$('.bottom').offset().top}, 300);

    }
      else{
          $('html, body').stop().animate({'scrollTop':$('.top').offset().top}, 300);
      }
```

Here is working example: http://jsfiddle.net/zB5bc/4/

Comment: where is your example

Comment: If you try scroll down in bottom div it's automatically going to bottom div top by the way if not use to button and try the scroll down in top div same problem here too.

Comment: Sorry but this is not true one because if I scroll up at the bottom div's bottom it's going to top div too. Here is the working example stadiumtechcenter.com/building when scroll up and page content area reach the top site automatically slide to page top.

Comment: After edit for my project it's working perfect now. Thank you!